# How to get the items inserted in the DOM using DOMNodeInserted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the values of items in a Dynamically generated DOM using DOMNodeInserted.
Here is my code.The items @I want to get the values are li eg

```
<div id="demo">    
    <ul>
        <li class="req">Chemistry</li>
        <li class="req">English</li>
        <li class="req">Maths</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code

```
$('#demo').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var that = $(this);
    if ($(e.target).is('.req')) {
        alert(oneoftheitemsintheli);
    }
});
```

I want to get on of the items in the `li` eg `Maths`, `Chemistry` etc. I need to know how to get the items.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that each `li` has the class `req`, you can use `each` to iterate over them and get the text value - or any other property you need.

```
$('#demo').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    $('.req').each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8bb29/)